# Not sure where these lines are coming from

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have stretched and expanded my columns to fill with grey. However, I see these fine lines as if it's not fully expanding or stretching.  I found this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25009) which states that it's an antialiasing problem and tried their suggestion with wrapping the container with another container. The lines are less visible but it's still there.  Is there any way to fix this?

[not sure where these lines are coming from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owahe.png)

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(Calculator());

class Calculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: InputPage(),
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
        // accentColor: Colors.purple,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

input_page.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'reuseable_button.dart';

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(flex: 5, child: Row()),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ReuseableButton(value: '1'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '2'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '3'),
                  ],
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ReuseableButton(value: '4'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '5'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '6'),
                  ],
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ReuseableButton(value: '7'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '8'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '9'),
                  ],
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ReuseableButton(value: '.'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '0'),
                    ReuseableButton(value: '='),
                  ],
                )),
              ],
            )),
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: Column())
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

reuseable_button.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReuseableButton extends StatelessWidget {
  ReuseableButton({this.value});
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Align(
              child: Text(value),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code again and I wrap your each Expanded widget that has row child or column child  with container in `InputPage` and `ReuseableButton` classes and set color for them like code below and it solved problem:

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(flex: 5, child: Row()),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ReuseableButton(value: '1'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '2'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '3'),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ReuseableButton(value: '4'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '5'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '6'),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ReuseableButton(value: '7'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '8'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '9'),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                  //color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ReuseableButton(value: '.'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '0'),
                      ReuseableButton(value: '='),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            )),
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: Column())
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class ReuseableButton extends StatelessWidget {
  ReuseableButton({this.value});
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Align(
                  child: Text(value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still visible on my emulator after making the suggested change.  I'm using a pixel 2xl. that kind of changes the layout as well.  Was hoping I can still get the same look to it.